# Assignment statement - considered harmful?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, assignment-operator, sicp

I came across [this video of Uncle Bob](http://cleancoder.posterous.com/stub-1-sicp-assignment) speaking about the [SICP book](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) and the assignment statement and it made me think (and read [the corresponding chapter from SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-20.html)).

I'm wondering whether the arguments listed (local state, side effects, etc.), considering the first edition was published in **1984**, are still a problem in modern languages like Java and C#. **It may have been a problem then. Is it still now? Or has something changed?**

For example in Java we have **immutable** `String`s. A particular area I can think of where assignment is detrimental is **concurrency** (*correct me if I'm wrong*). No assignment means no synchronization and no resource deadlocks, right?

Comment: @downvoter: care to say what's wrong with the question and how I can improve it?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245329/java-immutable-classes; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769607/why-do-we-need-immutable-class. (And see the comments at the latter for several more.)

Comment: Nothing you say is specific to the assignment statement/operator. Rather, it's about *mutability*.

Comment: @delnan: doesn't mutability imply the use of the assignment operator?

Comment: At some level, yes (but consider that the actual assignment may be hidden behind many method calls and possibly even some foreign function call). At least in all common approaches I can think of. But ultimately, assignment is just a mean to the end (mutability). And it's whether a value can change, not how it is changed, that matters.

Comment: How does this question not relate to programming or software development?

Comment: This would be a great question, if reworded a bit, for programmers.stackexchange.com